# Take the values from Pandas dataframe column and create a new column with them as a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe which looks like this:

`Record Field11   ID      LesionNumber      Diagnosis1

   1    False    1000           1                22

   1    False    1000           2                88

   1    False    1000           3                22

   1    False    1000           4                24`

All of the ID's are the same. And this kind of structure repeats for many different ID's.

Using all rows with the same ID, I'd like to create a new dataframe which looks like this:

`Record   ID      LesionNumber      Diagnosis1

   1     1000     1, 2, 3, 4       22, 88, 22, 24`

I'd like to have the `LesionNumber` and `Diagnosis1` appear as ordered lists.

I'm new to Pandas and dataframes so my terminology may be off. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `agg`

```
df.groupby(['Record','Field11','ID']).agg(lambda x : ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()
Out[634]: 
   Record  Field11    ID LesionNumber   Diagnosis1
0       1    False  1000      1,2,3,4  22,88,22,24
```